# Why is the Monster group the largest sporadic finite simple group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

I do know that there is a "long proof" (I have read that it is +1000pages) that the Monster group is the largest sporadic simple group. My question is:

Why can we be sure that there is no other bigger group out there?

Beyond that long proof, is there any alternative "proof" of why the Monster group is the largest simple group? After all, the full set of sporadic simple groups seems to have some unexplained and yet mysterious relationships between some of them.

Comment: The only thing to be sure of such a fact is a proof. There is a proof.

Comment: it seems like you're looking for an inuitive explanation, if so you might want to mention this in your question.

Comment: No, I am not asking for an intuitive reason. I wrote "proof" since, as a physicist, I am aware that sometimes purist mathematics argue that algebraic theorems must be proved by algebraic methods. However, for instance, complex analysis provides an easy way to "prove" that every n-th degree equation has exactly n(generally complex) roots. I am wondering the same here. I mean, that is there something in the theory of automorphic forms (j-invariant) via the moonshine that makes people confident about that the monster is really the largest sporadic group?

Comment: No one to date has, as far as I know,  given an a priori reason why there should only be finitely many sporadic simple groups. It seems though that there are. I suppose that if you did not believe the classification of finite simple groups, and wanted some "intuitive" explanation, it might be that to describe a new infinite collection of "sporadic" simple groups, you would have to have some parametrization or other uniform way of describing them, so you would introduce a new family of "known" groups. Almost by definition, only finitely many "sporadic" groups could be outside "known" families.

Comment: The Monster is *not* the largest simple group. It is not even the largest *non-abelian* simple group. It is merely the largest *sporadic* simple group. I believe, for example, that $E_{11}$ is larger.

Comment: Also, you might find that [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/38161/heuristic-argument-that-finite-simple-groups-ought-to-be-classifiable) Mathoverflow thread answers your question. It is certainly fascinating!

Comment: User1729, ramanujanized!;) Thanks, ...What is E_11?I believed the largest exceptional semisimple lie group was E_8!What is E_11? :O

Comment: @riemannium $E_{11}$ is what I came up with when I tried to think of $E_8$.

Comment: @user1729 You can find examples of groups a billion times bigger than the monster group in any of the infinite families of finite nonabelian simple groups.  I mean, hell, just take $A_{|M|}$, where $M$ is the Monster.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: I know, I was just coming up with an example, other than the obvious cyclic ones...

Comment: It's 10000 pages, by the way, not 1000, and even that may be a conservative estimate.

Comment: @user1729 Of course :) I was agreeing with you.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: Sorry, I was still slightly embarrassed after my $E_{11}$ non-example!

Comment: Actually $E_8$ is not a finite simple group either.  It is, however, the name of an infinite family of simple groups of Lie type whose smallest member, $E_8(2)$, is already larger than the Monster.